# Apticron notifying about uninstalled packages

Tags: apt, debian

I'm using apticron to notify myself about available updates.  However, I've got an installation on a VPN that seems to notify about packages I DON'T have installed.  For example, it keeps (daily) suggesting that I upgrade sysvinit - I have upstart installed, not sysvinit.  I used to have it for a number of other packages (basic libraries that weren't installed in my original Debian-wheezy image), so I've shut up those warnings just by installing the libraries.  However, I don't really want to ditch upstart for sysvinit just to make apticron play more nicely.

Any ideas how to make it stop?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found my own answer - and slightly embarrassed I didn't spot this in the config file before I posted:

```
# Set NOTIFY_NEW="0" if you don't want to be notified about packages which
# are not installed in your system. Yes, it's possible! There are some issues
# related to systems which have mixed stable/unstable sources. In these cases
# apt-get will consider for example that packages with "Priority:
# required"/"Essential: yes" in unstable but not in stable should be installed,
# so they will be listed in dist-upgrade output. Please take a look at
# http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=531002#44
```

sysvinit, of course, is considered required/essential (as were the others I had installed to silence the notifications).  So, setting

```
NOTIFY_NEW="0"
```

in `/etc/apticron/apticron.conf` solves the problem.